# Query Error only at runtime

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I have a strange behaviour where I execute a methods that run a query. It works on localhost but fails on the quality envoronement. The query and the error are the follows:

```
WITH t AS 
(
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY matricola  ORDER BY esercizio DESC, cod_valutazione, valutaz_sintetica, matricola, FigureOrder) AS RowN 
    FROM 
        (SELECT DISTINCT 
            '' AS pdf,
            Vm.NomeManager + ' ' + Vm.CognomeManager AS valutatore,
            vpd.ESERCIZIO AS esercizio,
            vpd.cod_valutazione,
            Vm.NomeValutato +' ' + Vm.CognomeValutato AS valutato,
            vpd.matricola,
            valutaz_sintetica,
            vpd.COD_STATO AS stato_scheda,
            vpd.VALUTAZIONE_RANKING_SINTETICA,
            vvv.COD_FIGURA,
            CASE
                WHEN COD_FIGURA = 'OWNG' THEN 0
                WHEN COD_FIGURA = 'VAL1' THEN 1
                WHEN COD_FIGURA = 'OWN' THEN 2
            END AS FigureOrder      
        FROM
            View_SchedePerDistribuzione vpd
            INNER JOIN RL_VALUTAZIONE_VALUTATI_VALUTATORI vvv ON vpd.COD_VALUTAZIONE = vvv.COD_VALUTAZIONE AND vpd.MATRICOLA = vvv.MATRICOLA_VALUTATO 
            INNER JOIN ValutatiManager  Vm ON vpd.MATRICOLA = Vm.MatricolaVAlutato AND vpd.COD_VALUTAZIONE = Vm.COD_VALUTAZIONE
        WHERE 
            vpd.cod_valutazione='PA_SCI_11-12_test' AND 
            vpd.cod_stato='PROP' AND 
            chiusa = 0 AND 
            valutaz_sintetica <> '' AND 
            VVV.COD_FIGURA IN ('VAL1', 'OWN', 'OWNG') AND 
            VVV.Matricola = '06000013' 
        ) AS tab) 

        SELECT * 
          FROM t
         WHERE RowN = 1
         ORDER BY esercizio DESC, cod_valutazione, valutaz_sintetica, matricola, FigureOrder
```

This is the error:

```
        nnString=Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Sourcexxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx;Password='xxx';Connect Timeout=xx System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): 
        Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.     
        at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)     
        at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)     
        at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)     
        at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)     
        at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)     
        at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)     
        at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)     
        at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)     
        at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)     
        at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)     
        at valDipLibrary.utility.getQuery(String qry, OleDbTransaction SqlTrn, String ConnString, Boolean fromPool, Boolean logReq, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecord)     
        at valDipLibrary.utility.getQuery(String qry, OleDbTransaction SqlTrn, String ConnString, Boolean fromPool, Boolean logReq, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecord)
```

More info:

If I run the query on my SSMS it works.
If I run the query on the SSMS of the quality server it works.

It does not works only if I run the method thet execute the query.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a semicolon before the word with

ie:

```
;WITH t AS  
( 
    SELECT 
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the qulaity server is of version less than 2005. Becuase CTE is supported from version 2005 onwards

Comment: Gotta like "qulaity servers"!  Prolly the right answer tho +1